# Have voronoi take into account line boundaries (such as rivers, highways...) (on Qgis 3.14)

Tags: qgis-3, voronoi-thiessen, catchment-area, geomarketing

I have points locating supermarkets. I would like to use the Voronoi method to automatically delineate the catchment area of each supermarket (in real life of course it overlaps a bit on each other but I don't need this level of detail). I am wondering if it is possible to take into account large physical or man-made obstacles which have a real effect on the catchment areas. For instance, a highway with few under or overpasses, a (large) river, a large drop in elevation... Can the Voronoi method (or any other method) take this into account if the obstacles are represented as open polylines? I guess that another way would be to manually crop the part of the voronoi area that intersect the obstacle but I wonder if there is a way to take this into account in the process itself.

Comment: I guess best way is indeed to do voronoi polygons and then split the polygons by the highways. Depending on your data, you don't have to do that manually. Or you can just select the supermarkets on one side of the river/highway and run voronoi just for the selected features.

Comment: I think that selecting the supermarkets on one side could be a good idea. Otherwise the problem is not just that some polygons should be split by the highways/rivers but that other polygons should also be extended to the river/highway edge. Another rough solution (unless there is a better automated one that we don't know about yet) would also be to run a normal voronoi and then manually edit the polygon vertices to match the boundary feature (river, highway...) since I don't need something super accurate anyway.

Comment: Did you see this post?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254593/voronoi-that-dont-cross-boundaries

Comment: Thank you, I had not seen it! It seems there is a lot in this CGAL library, although I don't think I would be able to use it due to my own technical limitations at the present time. But I will still check it into more detail.