# How to make constrained Thiessen polygons in ArcGIS Pro/QGIS 3.26

Tags: qgis, polygon, voronoi-thiessen, constraint

I want to make constrained Thiessen polygons in which the process of calculating polygons will stop when the each polygon touches the boundary line/coastline. How can I do it in ArcGIS Pro or in QGIS 3.26?

Here is an example:
[image]

I want these smaller parts of the red polygon to be part of the blue polygon.
I've managed to do it manually with Singlepart to Multipart and than merging them one by one. Is there any way to automate this process?

Comment: For QGIS, it is already answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254593/voronoi-that-dont-cross-boundaries)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please decide which of QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop you wish to ask about within this question so that it and its answers can be focused on what you have tried and where you are stuck.  If it's ArcGIS Desktop then do you wish to ask about ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Run multipart to single parts.
2. Select polygons that do not contain any of the points that were used to create the voronoi polygons.
3. Merge the selected polygons with the largest neighboring polygon.